# From a feature branch F1 with commits {A, B}, create a second feature F2 still having A, to start developing C on it. How merging both at the end?

Tags: git, merge, branch, rebase

From my `master` branch where last commit is **M**
I've created a first feature branch **F1**, with

- **A**, a commit of general refactoring inside
- and **B** the feature requested.

I'm called to realize another feature first : **F2**.
I want to keep from **F1** the **A** commit, then start the **C** one.

At a time, I think that **F2** will be the first being merged into `master`,
but whatever it's F1 {A,B} or F2 {A,C} that is chosen,
if I merge one feature branch, I would like be sure to merge the second one without trouble.

---

What are the good moves to do?
Is what I intend to do for that, below, correct and efficient enough?

1. From my **F1** branch, perform a `checkout -b F2`
2. In the **F2** branch, do a `git revert B` commit or a `rebase` to evict it
3. In the **F2** branch, perform my new development and commits **C** on it
4. F1 has now {A, B} and F2 {A, C}, if I choose **F2** for first feature being merged in `master` I'll do:
5. In the `master` branch, `git merge F2`
6. In the `F1` branch, will I be able to `rebase` from `master` to remove the mention of **A** commit, as is now in `master`?
   Is it necessary?
7. either F1 is now {B} only, and I do a `git merge F1` into `master`
   either it is still F1 {A, B} but it merges smoothly in `master` that is {M, A, C} at the moment?

Comment: No, revert is not what you need here. When you'll merge your F2 branch (which contains the revert commit) into your master, it would then effectively revert B on master. Don't revert anything to create your F2 branch. Rebase.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to revert. Revert means: these changes were bad, they should never have existed.

Instead, you want to start your branch at A:

```
git checkout -b F2 A
```

As long as B and C don't conflict, you should be safe to merge both branches into master. A is *not* merged twice, only once.

There can always be conflicts of course, but this is true for any two branches that are developed in parallel.

If you already know that F1 will be merged before F2, then it might make sense to base F2 on F1 (including commits A+B). Git is smart enough to merge A+B only once when you merge F2 (which only contains additional commit C)

The history after merging both branches is going to look like this:

```
...-o--o---M1--M2    < master
     \    /   /
      A--B   /       < F1
       \    /
        `--C         < F2
```

Commit `M2` only contains the additional changes of `C`.

Comment: Thanks! However, the `git checkout -b F2 A` didn't succeed in keeping only A. It took A and B, so that I will rebase my branch to remove B.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan if A is the parent of B, then the branch created by `checkout -b F2 A` cannot contain B. It's impossible

Comment: your right! I've mistaken and put the other commit in my `checkout -b` command :-)